# is there a std::optional_function like the given

Tags: c++, std, function-pointers

I am searching for something like swifts ? operator in c++ for std::function.  I have grown to like it over the last couple years.

I would like a std::optional_function, which only calls the function if the function exists.

Something like this (but written by the gods of c++):

```
template<typename R>
struct option_function_result {
    bool executed;
    R result;
} ;

template<>
struct option_function_result<void>
{
    bool executed;
} ;

template<typename F>
class optional_function
{
public:
    typedef std::function<F> function_type;
    typedef option_function_result<typename function_type::result_type> result_type;

protected:
    function_type f;

public:

    template<typename Fn>
    optional_function operator=(const Fn &f_)
    {
        f = f_;
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename Fn>
    optional_function operator=(Fn &&f_)
    {
        f = std::forward<Fn>(f_);
        return *this;
    }

    operator bool() const
    {
        return (bool)f;
    }

    template<typename ...Args, typename R>
    result_type operator()(Args... args)
    {
        if (f)
            return result_type { true, f(args...) };

        return result_type { false };
    }

    template<typename ...Args>
    result_type operator()(Args... args)
    {
        if (f)
        {
            f(args...);
            return result_type { true };
        }

        return result_type { false };
    }

} ;
```

### Another revision

Here is revision 2.  In order not to polute the question, and since I don't know if this will be a final answer, I'm gonna place it here for now:

I expect that the constructor for the struct is not necessary.  However it forces the compiler to give me errors I need to debug the compilation.

---

```
template<typename R>
struct optional_function_result {
    bool executed;
    R result;

    optional_function_result(bool &&executed_, R &&result_) :
        executed (executed_),
        result(result_) {}
} ;

template<>
struct optional_function_result<void>
{
    bool executed;

    optional_function_result(bool &&executed_) :
        executed (executed_) {}
} ;

template<typename F>
class optional_function
{
public:
    typedef std::function<F> function_type;
    typedef typename std::function<F>::result_type function_result_type;
    typedef optional_function_result<typename function_type::result_type> result_type;

protected:
    function_type f;

public:

    template<typename Fn>
    optional_function operator=(const Fn &f_)
    {
        f = f_;
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename Fn>
    optional_function operator=(Fn &&f_)
    {
        f = std::forward<Fn>(f_);
        return *this;
    }

    operator bool() const
    {
        return (bool)f;
    }

    template<
        typename ... Args,
        typename FR=function_result_type,
        typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<FR>::value, FR>::type* = nullptr
    >
    result_type operator()(Args... args) const
    {
        if (f)
            return {
                true,
                std::forward<typename function_type::result_type>(f(args...))
            };

        return {
            false,
            function_result_type()
        };
    }

    template<
        typename ... Args,
        typename FR=function_result_type,
        typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<FR>::value, FR>::type* = nullptr
    >
    result_type operator()(Args... args) const
    {
        if (f)
        {
            f(args...);
            return { true };
        }

        return { false };
    }
} ;
```

### Ok one more version, which uses basically optional to get rid of some edge cases.

```
template<typename T>
using optional_type = std::experimental::optional<T>;

template<typename R>
struct optional_function_result : optional_type<R> {
    typedef optional_type<R> super_type;

    optional_function_result() :
        super_type() {}

    optional_function_result(R &&result_) :
        super_type(result_) {}

    bool executed() const { return this->has_result(); }
} ;

template<>
struct optional_function_result<void>
{
    bool executed_;

    optional_function_result(bool &&executed__) :
        executed_ (executed__) {}

    bool executed() const { return executed_; }
} ;

template<typename F>
class optional_function
{
public:
    typedef std::function<F> function_type;
    typedef typename std::function<F>::result_type function_result_type;
    typedef optional_function_result<typename function_type::result_type> result_type;

protected:
    function_type f;

public:

    template<typename Fn>
    optional_function operator=(const Fn &f_)
    {
        f = f_;
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename Fn>
    optional_function operator=(Fn &&f_)
    {
        f = std::forward<Fn>(f_);
        return *this;
    }

    operator bool() const
    {
        return (bool)f;
    }

    template<
        typename ... Args,
        typename FR=function_result_type,
        typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<FR>::value, FR>::type* = nullptr
    >
    result_type operator()(Args... args) const
    {
        if (f)
            return {
                std::forward<typename function_type::result_type>(f(args...))
            };

        return {};
    }

    template<
        typename ... Args,
        typename FR=function_result_type,
        typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<FR>::value, FR>::type* = nullptr
    >
    result_type operator()(Args... args) const
    {
        if (f)
        {
            f(args...);
            return { true };
        }

        return { false };
    }
} ;
```

Comment: Your `R` must be default-constructible. Though I suppose you could make it `std::optional<R>`

Comment: `operator=(const Fn &f_)` is pretty useless because the other overloads forwards but `operator()` will alway copy and not forward. Your first overload of the call operator cannot be called. You should redefine what you consider "C++ gods"

Comment: Can you show an example use case for those of us not familiar with Swift?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional

Comment: How are you expecting to call the first overload of `operator()`? `R` will never be deducable since you can't explicitly specify it. It comes after a pack.

Comment: How about [Boost.Optional](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: @Mafor Not relevant. Also we use `std::optional` now, not `boost::optional`

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 yeah, editing

Comment: example in swift might be something like:  var myoptionalfunc : (()->())? = nil; myoptionalfunc?()    <---  this will not crash

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I consider the people that moved c++ through c++11/14/17 -> gods.  C++ is so much more amazing now than it was 20 years ago. :-)

Comment: Added another possible version

Answer (score 3):

The `?` operator works really well in C++ too:

```
// let function be of type std::function or a function pointer
auto var = f ? f() : default_value;
```

If you really want a type that does that, there is no such thing in the standard library, but a simple function is enough to do what you want (works only for function that don't return references or void):

```
template<typename F, typename... Args, typename R = std::invoke_result_t<F, Args&&...>>
auto optionally_call(F&& f, Args&&... args) -> std::optional<R> {
    return f ? R(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) : std::nullopt;
}
```

With some metaprogramming, it's possible to support cases not supported by this implementation.

This is to highlight that there's a lot of pitfalls when creating a whole type that is meant to be generic. There are many mistakes and performance issues and even code that will cannot be called in your sample code. A simple utility function would be easier than a type.

Comment: Note that your `optionally_call` fails when the callable returns a reference.

Comment: also void problems

Comment: yes I know the ? operator, sort of crappy code, especially if no return value -- by that I mean, std optional doesn't handle <void>.. Which is basically why I was thinking to implement some sort of solution like the one above (but would much rather find something in std already)

Comment: For bonus points, also execute `f` if it cannot be converted to boolean. And avoid double-wrapping in `std::optional`.

Comment: Double-wrapping?

Comment: My aim was to be very simple in the answer, and just provide aim for a better solution so OP can continue in the right path. Of course I know Reference and void don't work, I told it in the answer.

Comment: @Deduplicator `And avoid double-wrapping` I would very much not do that in generic code.

Comment: As you say, there are also reason to do it, and with `std::optional` in contrast to `std::reference_wrapper` it at least generally works. (forgot to upvote. Fixed ;-))

Answer (score 1):

The standard library doesn't have anything like that, but you can build one yourself:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

template <typename T>
class optional_function {
 private:
  std::optional<T> func;

 public:
  optional_function(T f) : func{std::move(f)} {}

  optional_function() = default;

  template <typename... Args>
  auto operator()(Args&&... args) const {
    using func_invoke_type = decltype((*func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...));

    constexpr bool func_invoke_type_is_void = std::is_same_v<void, func_invoke_type>;

    using optional_result_type = std::optional<
        std::conditional_t<
            func_invoke_type_is_void, // Can't have a std::optional<void>
            char,
            std::conditional_t<
                std::is_reference_v<func_invoke_type>, // Can't have a std::optional<T&>
                std::reference_wrapper<std::remove_reference_t<func_invoke_type>>,
                func_invoke_type
            >
        >
    >;

    if (func) {
      if constexpr (!func_invoke_type_is_void) {
        return optional_result_type{(*func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)};
      } else {
        (*func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return optional_result_type{ '\0' }; //  can't return void{} '
      }
    }
    return optional_result_type{};
  }
};

// Test it

void foo() {}

int main() {
  optional_function f1{[](int i) { return i * i; }};
  optional_function f2{[] { std::cout << "Hello World\n"; }};
  decltype(f1) f3{};
  optional_function f4{[](int a, const int& b) -> int const& {
    std::cout << a + b << '\n';
    return b;
  }};

  optional_function f5{foo};

  auto res1 = f1(9);
  auto res2 = f2();
  auto res3 = f3(9);
  int b = 5;
  auto res4 = f4(1, b);
  auto res5 = f5();

  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << "f1 is executed: " << res1.has_value() << ". result: " << *res1
            << '\n';
  std::cout << "f2 is executed: " << res2.has_value() << '\n';
  std::cout << "f3 is executed: " << res3.has_value() << '\n';
  std::cout << "f4 is executed: " << res4.has_value() << ". result: " << *res4
            << '\n';
  std::cout << "f5 is executed: " << res5.has_value() << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is currently no such thing in the C++ Standard Library.